# Is it allowed to cache static google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I'm having some issue with static Google maps generation. The API has "a query limit of 1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day. Since this restriction is a quota per viewer, most developers should not need to worry about exceeding their quota".

However when using a shared connection, as instance with a mobile phone and a 3G access (phone operators), this limit seems to be problematic.

Hence my question is the following: can I retrieve the image server-side and serve it to my clients? Is it allowed?

Comment: Would you please share the code you used to store the maps? :-)

Comment: It was 5 years ago, i'm don't use it anymore. But I'm pretty sure you don't need me to write a file on the disk...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This FAQ indicates not: [Can I generate a map image using the Google Static Maps API which I store and serve from my website?](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_staticmaps_reuse)

Text (as of November 2016):

> **Can I generate a map image using the Google Static Maps API which I store and serve from my website?**
>
> You may not store and serve copies of images generated using the Google Static Maps API from your website. All web pages that require static images must link the src attribute of an HTML img tag or the CSS background-image attribute of an HTML div tag directly to the Google Static Maps API so that all map images are displayed within the HTML content of the web page and served directly to end users by Google.

Comment: I think you found the answer. I'll post on the google group concerning the problem of quota limitation combined with mobile 3G access.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you can. Reference [the Google Maps TOS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/):

> 3.2.4 *Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.*
>
> (a)  *No Scraping.*  Customer will not extract, export, or scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not:(i) pre-fetch, cache, index, or store Google Maps Content for more than 30 days; (ii) bulk download geocodes; or (iii) copy business names, addresses, or user reviews.

*(Edit: Updated to reflect the latest terms as of June 2018.)*

This is discussed in further detail in the "Sanity Checks" aspect of [Google Static Maps Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#sanity).

Comment: No. A single static map image may fit within your interpretation of "limited amount of Content", compared to say "all the static maps possible", but I think it's pretty clear (given the other quotes) that Google see this as an entire end result, so not a limited amount of Content.

In any event, displaying a cached copy to a user would unarguably permit use of the Content outside of the Service.

So this clause does not, sadly, give us carte blanche to store maps on our servers.

Comment: @PaulGregory how about client side storage? Do you know what the restrictions on that are?

Comment: The "for more than 30 days" part was removed in July 2018

Comment: Google's tips on how to limit service usage hits suggest to cache it as per Cache-Controll. So maybe you cannot cache bitmap perse, but whole WS response is fine. https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/optimize-web-services#cache

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 21 2021, both [ToS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) and [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#understanding-terms-of-service) are speaking the same language. Storing and serving copies of images generated using the Google Static Maps API from your website is not allowed.

ToS

> 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.
>
> (a)  No Scraping. Customer will not export, extract, or otherwise scrape Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download Google Maps tiles, Street View images, geocodes, directions, distance matrix results, roads information, places information, elevation values, and time zone details; (iii) copy and save business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services.

FAQ

> Can I generate a map image using the Maps Static API which I store and serve from my website?
>
> You may not store and serve copies of images generated using the Maps Static API from your website. All web pages that require static images must link the `src` attribute of an HTML `img` tag or the CSS `background-image` attribute of an HTML `div` tag directly to the Maps Static API so that all map images are displayed within the HTML content of the web page and served directly to end users by Google.

Answer (score 2):

I find the TOS pretty contradictory

> **Can I generate a map image using the Google Static Maps API which I store and serve from my website?**
>
> You may not store and serve copies of images generated using the
>   Google Static Maps API from your website. All web pages that require
>   static map images must link the src attribute of an HTML img tag or
>   the CSS background-image attribute of an HTML div tag directly to the
>   Google Static Maps API so that all map images are displayed within the
>   HTML content of the web page and served directly to end users by
>   Google.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits